# ViewPager prevent from Destroying View

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, view

I wanted to know if there is any function which i can prevent the ViewPager from destroying the 1 view.

I have like 100 Views which are permanantly the option to jump back to the first one, so i dont want to close the first one. The Offscreenlimit is not an option beacause all other Views should be cloused without the 1 one.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A `ViewPager` does not destroy views. A most, a `PagerAdapter` destroys views, and the rules for when and how it does so are up to the implementation of the `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: Ok thanks, than i just searched on the wrong position. :/